# Different Membership behaviour in Chrome and IE9 in ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application. In this application, for logged user, Membership.GetUser() returns null when working in Chrome... and it works just fine in IE9.
Could anyone get me an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What version of chrome do you have?

Comment: Try removing all cookies in both ie and chrome and see if the behaviour is still different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 23 - everything works fine!